# Passing data between a class and a functional component - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I am using React and React Router.

Here is my first component:

```
import React from 'react';

class SomeClass extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
              someObj: {
                something: "",
                someOtherThing: ""
              },
            authenticated: false
        };
    }

}



export default SomeClass;
```

Here is my ProtectedRoute component:
const ProtectedRoute = ({auth, component: Component, ...rest}) =>{
return(
<Route {...rest} render={(props) =>{

```
            if(auth){
                return(<Component {...props} />);
            }

            if(!auth){
                return(<Redirect to={{path: "/", state:{from: props.location}}} />);
            }
        }} />
    );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Here is my Nav component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import ProtectedRoute from './ProtectedRoute';
import SomeClass from './SomeClass';

function Nav(){
    return(
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/somepage/abc" component={SomeClass} auth={SomeClass.props.authenticated} />  //getting an error here because of SomeClass.props.authenticated
            </Switch>
        </Router>

    );
}


export default Nav;
```

My Question:

In my Nav functional component, there is the <ProtectedRoute ....>, I want to get the authenticated value from the SomeClass's authenticated value (this.state.authenticated)?

When I do SomeClass.props.authenticated I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticated' of undefined

Comment: can you add what error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

you can pass it down in the form of a prop

in the `someClass` :

- import Nav
- type the following

```
<Nav auth = {this.state.authenticated}/>
```

and the `Nav` component should be as follows:

```
function Nav(props){
    return(
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/somepage/abc" component={SomeClass} auth={props.auth} /> 
            </Switch>
        </Router>

    );
}
```